I'm not able to render data in the prime react editor
b static data also isn't rendering in the PrimeReact Editor.There is data in the the backend the data is coming in fine but it doesn't show up on the editor
I was trying to render the data to get to display it on the editor but even static data seems to fail nothing shows up on the editor, I'm able to type in it though

This question doesn't include enough information for an answer. Please see How to Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You are trying to use QuillJS 2.0.0+ with an older PrimeReact. You either need to downgrade to QuillJS 1.3.7 or upgrade your PrimeReact to 10.6.5 or higher.
See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/5960
